# sudden shutdown Ubuntu 16.04 - Dell inspiron 13 7000

Tags: 16.04, dell, shutdown, inspiron

I have a dell inspiron 13 7368, running Ubuntu 16.04
Everything is fine and smooth except that it happened more than once that it just shuts down suddenly, like if you unplug the power without battery, it is always running on battery when this happens.

any suggestions ? where to look or what to test?

EDIT: syslog entries (last entry is after the crash)

```
Sep 25 16:18:25 codename kernel: [60639.501898] dell_wmi: Unknown WMI event type 0x00: 0xe00c
Sep 25 16:18:25 codename kernel: [60639.501902] dell_wmi: Unknown WMI event type 0x00: 0x3
Sep 25 16:18:25 codename kernel: [60639.817472] ACPI Error: Thread 500455552 cannot release Mutex [PATM] acquired by thread 1054886336 (20150930/exmutex-399)
Sep 25 16:18:25 codename kernel: [60639.817493] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66] (Node ffff8802468e5ca8), AE_AML_NOT_OWNER (20150930/psparse-542)
Sep 25 16:18:25 codename kernel: [60639.837129] dell_wmi: Unknown WMI event type 0x00: 0xe00c
Sep 25 16:18:25 codename kernel: [60639.837139] dell_wmi: Unknown WMI event type 0x00: 0x1
Sep 25 16:18:51 codename systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Sep 25 16:31:52 codename systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Sep 25 16:35:03 codename systemd[1618]: Time has been changed
Sep 25 16:35:03 codename systemd-timesyncd[614]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Sep 25 16:35:03 codename systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Sep 25 16:35:03 codename systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 2h 4min 7.736824s random time.
Sep 25 16:35:03 codename systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 5h 21min 12.369915s random time.
Sep 25 16:39:01 codename CRON[10280]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
Sep 25 16:44:53 codename systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Sep 25 16:57:54 codename systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Sep 25 17:09:01 codename CRON[10703]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
Sep 25 17:10:55 codename systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Sep 25 17:17:01 codename CRON[10880]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 25 17:23:55 codename systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Sep 25 17:36:56 codename systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Sep 25 17:39:01 codename CRON[11177]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
Sep 25 17:49:57 codename systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Sep 25 18:02:57 codename systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Sep 25 18:09:01 codename CRON[11785]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
Sep 25 18:13:37 codename org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1788]: Kinit for 985353 to access (null) failed: Cannot determine realm for host
Sep 25 18:15:58 codename systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Sep 25 18:17:01 codename CRON[11965]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 25 18:25:28 codename dbus[733]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Sep 25 18:25:28 codename systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Sep 25 18:25:28 codename dbus[733]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Sep 25 18:25:28 codename systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Sep 25 18:25:30 codename gnome-session[1943]: (nautilus:2093): Gtk-WARNING **: Refusing to add non-unique action 'TerminalNautilus:OpenFolderLocal' to action group 'ExtensionsMenuGroup'
Sep 25 18:26:21 codename gnome-session[1943]: message repeated 6 times: [ (nautilus:2093): Gtk-WARNING **: Refusing to add non-unique action 'TerminalNautilus:OpenFolderLocal' to action group 'ExtensionsMenuGroup']
Sep 25 18:28:59 codename systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Sep 25 18:36:50 codename rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="740" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

Comment: Need details. Are you using Nvidia proprietary drivers? Have you applied updates for all packages?  What are you doing when crash happens? I did have your problem for first month of Ubuntu 1604 on a Dell 5510. Updating Intel video driver along with many other updates has solved freezes. If you have consistent kernel panic, some folks here can help recover error files. In your /var/log folder, text logs should have evidence of crash cause. Look at messages files

Comment: no Nvidia. I had everything updated. not kernel panic, I checked that.
about what I was doing.. more like everything.. I use my laptop almost all the time.. never shutdown.. more than 5 programs open at any time (Chrome, IDE, office, mail, terminal, etc..) most likely Chrome is active when it happens
I'll edit to share the latest syslog entries, I believe it is clean

Comment: We need to see the part of /var/log/syslog that happened `just before/during` the shutdown. Cheers, Al

Comment: Does this shutdown occur when it's plugged into AC power? Cheers, Al

Comment: Please see my updated answer, below. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a bad battery. But lets try and reset the power manager.

Unplug the computer from AC, and remove the battery (if it's removable). Hold down the power button for 10-15 seconds. Reinstall the battery and reconnect the AC adapter (if you wish) and see if that solves your shutdown problem.

You can also check the system log file by, in terminal, type `more /var/log/syslog` and find nearby the time that you had a shutdown. Look specifically for any temperature related messages. If found, it would indicate that your machine is overheating, causing the shutdowns.

There's also a BIOS (and a firmware) update available that might help. See `http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-13-7368-2-in-1-laptop/drivers`, and select BIOS (or ALL) as the category.

Cheers, Al

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what this long press of power button does, looks like it worked for me on ubuntu 18.04 dell n7110 with phoneix bios A13

Comment: @RajatVerma sometimes the power control circuitry gets confused, and the long press resets it.